# Do I have to get all the kills for the Federal Crime trophy in one game?

Tags: payday-the-heist

There is a trophy for Payday: The Heist called Federal Crime.  The trophy description is:

> Defeat 25 FBI agents in a row.

I am wondering if I need to get all 25 kills in one game or can I kill 15 agents in a row in one game and then 10 in a row at the start of another.

The in-game challenge section for it does not show a progress bar (which makes me think it might need to be all in one map) but since I can't check the progress I don't know if I don't have it because I accidentally killed someone else or if it needs to be done all in one game.

Comment: I found no indications you can do this in two games, but I don't have the game to test. I did find [this video guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GT1Bn0wXGzU) for the trophy though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be all in one map. It's a very hard achievement on Steam.  I believe [less than 1% of players](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/PAYDAY:TheHeist/achievements/) have it.  It helps to have a friend kill the anyone who isn't an FBI agent.